# Spelling numbers from digits to words

Tags: python

Using Python, write a function that takes a whole number as an argument and returns a string containing the number spelled out in English. For example, the function call:

```
 spell(123123)
```

will return the string:

```
        "one hundred twenty three thousand one hundred twenty three"
```

This is my code so far but I'm stuck. my code keeps printing the words "billion" "million" and "thousand" even for smaller numbers. How do I prevent that?

```
"""
This file contains functions that are helpful for spelling out numbers.
"""


def digit_name(digit):
    """
    Returns a string containing the English word naming "digit".
    "digit" must be between 1 and 9, inclusive
    """
    if digit == 1:
        return "one"
    if digit == 2:
        return "two"
    if digit == 3:
        return "three"
    if digit == 4:
        return "four"
    if digit == 5:
        return "five"
    if digit == 6:
        return "six"
    if digit == 7:
        return "seven"
    if digit == 8:
        return "eight"
    if digit == 9:
        return "nine"
    return ""


def teen_name(number):
    """
    Returns a string containing the English word naming "number".
    "number" must be between 10 and nineteen inclusive.
    """
    if number == 10:
        return "ten"
    if number == 11:
        return "eleven"
    if number == 12:
        return "twelve"
    if number == 13:
        return "thirteen"
    if number == 14:
        return "fourteen"
    if number == 15:
        return "fifteen"
    if number == 16:
        return "sixteen"
    if number == 17:
        return "seventeen"
    if number == 18:
        return "eighteen"
    if number == 19:
        return "nineteen"
    return ""


def tens_name(number):
    """
    Returns a string containing the English word for just the tens part of 
"number".
    "number" must be an integer between 20 and 99 inclusive.
    """
    if number >= 90:
        return "ninety"
    if number >= 80:
        return "eighty"
    if number >= 70:
        return "seventy"
    if number >= 60:
        return "sixty"
    if number >= 50:
        return "fifty"
    if number >= 40:
        return "forty"
    if number >= 30:
        return "thirty"
    if number >= 20:
        return "twenty"
    return ""


def spell_number_less_than_thousand(number):
    """
    Returns a string containing the English words that spell out "number".
    "number" must be between 0 and 1000, exclusive.
    """
    part = number  # the part that still needs to be converted
    name = ""  # the name of the number
    if part >= 100:
        name = digit_name(part // 100) + " hundred"
        part = part % 100
    if part >= 20:
        name = name + " " + tens_name(part)
        part = part % 10
    elif part >= 10:
        name = name + " " + teen_name(part)
        part = 0
    if part > 0:
        name = name + " " + digit_name(part)
    return name
# all the above code was provided by my teacher and the below is mine that I can change



def spell(num):
    s = ''
    if num < 0:
        s = s + "minus "
        num = num * -1
    s1 = ''
    x = num % 1000

    s1 = s1 + spell_number_less_than_thousand(x)
    num = int(num / 1000)

    y = num % 1000

    s1 = spell_number_less_than_thousand(y) + " Thousand " + s1
    num = int(num / 1000)

    z = num % 1000

    s1 = spell_number_less_than_thousand(z) + " Million " + s1
    num = int(num / 1000)

    t = num % 1000
    s1 = spell_number_less_than_thousand(t) + " Billion " + s1
    num = int(num / 1000)
    return s + s1


print(spell(100))
```

For the number, 100 it should only write the word "hundred" but instead I get "Billion  Million  Thousand one hundred". Most of the first part in the code was provided by my teacher that I can't change and the bottom one is mine.

Comment: As I already said in my answer, "_The idea is to print the highest value from the given number and then iterate on the remaining_". If the number if `100`, you don't need to continue with adding Billion etc. because the value is not large enough. If the number is 101, you will print "one hundred", reduce the number by 100, and iterate on the remaining (1). So, at each iteration, find the highest "suffix" in the number, print that, and iterate.

Answer (score 0):

This question comes from [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/integer-to-english-words/description/). Here’s a solution. The idea is to print the highest value from the given number and then iterate on the remaining. Some edge cases need to be handled, like leading zeros.

```
from collections.abc import Mapping
import itertools

class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        self.words: Mapping[str, str] = {
            "0": "Zero",
            "1": "One",
            "2": "Two",
            "3": "Three",
            "4": "Four",
            "5": "Five",
            "6": "Six",
            "7": "Seven",
            "8": "Eight",
            "9": "Nine",
            "10": "Ten",
            "11": "Eleven",
            "12": "Twelve",
            "13": "Thirteen",
            "14": "Fourteen",
            "15": "Fifteen",
            "16": "Sixteen",
            "17": "Seventeen",
            "18": "Eighteen",
            "19": "Nineteen",
            "20": "Twenty",
            "30": "Thirty",
            "40": "Forty",
            "50": "Fifty",
            "60": "Sixty",
            "70": "Seventy",
            "80": "Eighty",
            "90": "Ninety"
        }

        self.suffixes: Mapping[int, str] = {
            3: "Hundred",
            4: "Thousand",
            5: "Thousand",
            6: "Thousand",
            7: "Million",
            8: "Million",
            9: "Million",
            10: "Billion"
        }
    def numberToWords(self, num: int) -> str:
        return self._loop(str(num))
    
    def _trim_leading_zeros(self, i: str) -> str:
        return "".join(itertools.dropwhile(lambda ch: ch == "0", i))
        
    def _loop(self, i: str) -> str:
        n = len(i)
        if i in self.words:
            return self.words[i]
        if n == 2:
            return f"{self.words[i[0] + '0']} {self.words[i[1]]}"
        first = second = ""
        if n == 3:
            first = i[0]
            second = i[-2:]
        elif n <= 6:
            first = i[:(n - 3)]
            second = i[-3:]
        elif n <= 9:
            first = i[:(n - 6)]
            second = i[-6:]
        else:
            first = i[:(n - 9)]
            second = i[-9:]
        result: list[str] = [self._loop(first), self.suffixes[n]]
        x = self._trim_leading_zeros(second)
        if x:
            result.append(self._loop(x))
        return " ".join(result)
```

Comment: I can't use that because I must use the first part of my code that was provided by my teacher and I must have the statement "print(spell(100))" in my code

Comment: @HarrySingh I've given you an explanation of how the code works, and a working solution. Instead of looking for code that you can copy-paste and cheat in your homework, I'd advise you to understand the logic and implement it in the format given by your teacher.

Comment: im not trying to cheat but im in 3rd week of my first python class and most of the code you sent is too advance for me and I cant understand that. I've done most of my code and it kind of works but doesn't remove the extra "billion million thousand" thats all I need help with. thanks